# Azure mobile engagment xamarin port

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-engagement

Any one know the availability of Azure mobile engagement sdk for XAMARIN?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-ios-get-started/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Engagement is not available on Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

There's no SDK available for Xamarin for Azure Mobile Engagement.

If you really need to leverage Azure Mobile Engagement in Xamarin - I'd recommend you to check out the REST API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn913756.aspx

Comment: REST API does not replace a SDK, its just a companion. For example you need first to use a SDK on a mobile device before being able to use the REST API to set tags on that device or push campaigns on it.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin SDK as well as Unity [are now available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mobile-engagement-xamarin-unity-apis/)

Here's the Nuget package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Engagement.Xamarin/